# Input() in python not working when after another input()

Tags: python

When I have a line that has input() on it, the input() line after the first won't work when both are after each other. Here is my code.

```
from random import randint
you = 100
troll = 50
sword = randint(5,20)
goblin_attack = randint(25,50)
heal = you + 25
t_f = randint(1,2)
print("______________________")
print("WELCOME TO DRAGON GAME")
print("WRITE YOUR NAME......")
x = input()
print("Hello,")
print(x)
print("Lets begin....")
print("______________________")
print("You are in a troll cave")
print("A troll attacks!")
print("Quick, Dodge or attack,type D or A ")
print("______________________")
if input() == "D":
  print("You attempt to dodge out of it's swing!")
if t_f == 1:
  print("You dodge and attack!")
print("You hit the troll for")
print(sword)
print("damage")
print("It has")
print(troll - sword)
print("health left!")
if t_f == 2:
  print("You trip! you got hit for")
print(goblin_attack)
print("damage!")
print("You have")
print(you - goblin_attack)
you2 = you- goblin_attack
print("Health left!")
if input() == "A":
 print("You hit the troll for")
print(sword)
print("damage")
print("It has")
print(troll - sword)
print("health left!")
```

When I press A and hit enter, Nothing happens. But when I press D, it works. The first one always works no matter what I change the input to. Anyone have any idea how I can make both `input`s work?

Comment: Please fix your indentation—at least the line after `if input() == "D":` should be indented.

Comment: each `input()` call waits for your response. You are essentially taking the input twice instead of (i suspect) just once as you actually want. take the input once, and store what the user enters in a variable. use THAT variable for checking. `user_response = input()` `if user_response == 'D' ` and `if user_response == 'A'`

Comment: As @ParitoshSingh said, you should only take the input once, like `move=input("Quick, Dodge or attack,type D or A ")` Also, rather than 2 if statements, I would recommend  if/else or if/elif for your different response conditions

Answer (score 1):

Each `input` call waits for a keyboard input, so when you call `input()` twice, you're asking for *two* keyboard inputs.

To fix, change your code to something like so:

```
user_input = input()
if user_input == 'D':
    # go through the "dodge" scenario
elif user_input == 'A':
    # go through the "attack" scenario
```